# Python imports with __init__.py in a sibling directory

Tags: python, python-import

My directory structure looks like this:

```
 - scripts
   - script.py
 - app
  - foo
    - connect.py
  - bar
    - __init__.py
    - random.py
```

The `__init__.py` file in `bar/` looks like

```
from bar.random import Random

__all__ = [ "Random" ]
```

and `connect.py` has an import

```
from bar import Random
```

I'm trying to execute `script.py` from the root directory via `python scripts/script.py` which is attempting to import from `foo.py`

```
from os import getcwd
from sys import path
path.append(getcwd())

from app.foo.connect import Connect
```

and getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scripts/script.py", line 19, in <module>
    from app.foo.connect import Connect
  File "/home/user/project/app/foo/connect.py", line 17, in <module>
    from bar import Random
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bar'
```

When running the app through its main, everything works. But when trying to execute a specific script attempting to import from a subdirectory in `app/` I get the traceback.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have a look at the docs about [package-relative imports](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports), does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

The correct import of Random in connect.py is `from app.bar.random import Random`.

Also include `__init__.py` file in the `app` folder and `connect` folder.

You also do not need the `__all__` statement in the one `__init__.py` file you have. All the `__init__.py` files can be left blank.